# Animating bottom triangle with icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a triangle at the bottom of the screen with I want to animate into view (from the bottom) when a class gets applied to it.

css

```
.fade-in { bottom: -30px; }
.btn-visible.fade-in #top-btn-BG { bottom: 0; }

#top-btn a {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 padding: 30px 30px 25px 25px;
 color: #707070;
 bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#top-btn-BG {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 950;
  border-width: 0 0 125px 125px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  right: 0;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

html

```
  <div id="top-btn" class="flex fade-in">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scrolltop();"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up fa-lg"></i></a>
    <div id="top-btn-BG"></div>
  </div>
```

php

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// adjust this number to select when your button appears on scroll-down
var offset = 300,
scroll_top_duration = 3000,

// bind with the button link
$animation = $('.fade-in');

// apply animation
$(window).scroll(function(){
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $animation.addClass('btn-visible') :
    $animation.removeClass('btn-visible');
});

...
```

The script works by applying btn-visible to .fade-in whne the user scrolls.
I just cant get it to animate. (where to apply transition css to make sure the entire #top-btn div to animate up/down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused about the purpose behind top-btn-bg since it's literally invisible. You'll want to move your positioning and class change to the top-level container for the button regardless, I think, and then change the order so your later declarations take priority, like this...

```
#top-btn {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 padding: 30px 30px 25px 25px;
 color: #707070;
 bottom: -30px; 
 right: 0;
}
#top-btn.fade-in{
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: That creates the background triangle shape. (using the border). #top-btn a has an icon in it and is positioned overtop the triangle. I want to animate both as one on/off screen, when btn-visible is applied

Comment: Gotcha! Missed the #FFF part because it's grayed out for some reason - the above should still do the trick!